# How to send Http Form with parameters by ktor-client

Tags: kotlin, httpclient, ktor

I've found nearly everywhere in ktor-client documentation and examples they use empty formData to show how the client works

```
formParameters: Parameters = Parameters.Empty
```

So what's the kotlin/ktor way to fill it with parameters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ktor uses this approach to fill the parameters:

```
client.submitForm<HttpResponse>(
        url = "https://foo.com/login",
        formParameters = Parameters.build {
            append("_username", username)
            append("_password", password)
        })
```

Comment: This is the only thing that actually works. append is marked as internal for some reason but the other suggestions on this question either end up sending zero byte forms (!!) or appending url parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can also simply pass the form data using `formData`, e.g.:

```kotlin
client.post<HttpResponse>("https://example.com/login") {
    formData {
        parameter("username", username)
        parameter("password", password)
    }
}
```

Comment: this would not send any formdata and instead encodes parameters in the url. It will POST a zero byte form to a URL with the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I've found at least three ways to post www-urlencoded form:

```kotlin
return httpClient.submitForm("url") {
    parameter("key", "value")
}

return httpClient.post("url") {
    FormDataContent(Parameters.build {
        parameter("key", "value")
    })
}

return httpClient.post("url") {
    formData {
        parameter("key", "value")
    }
}
```

append() method is marked as internal and not working with ktor 1.6.4

Comment: unfortunately, parameter just encodes things into the url instead of the form payload. It's an extension function on  HttpRequestBuilder that adds url parameters. Always.  So useless for POSTing a multipart form.

Comment: I Agree. But some webservers support both variants. For example, I'm using this approach for posting to Google Forms, and it works well with empty body and encoded values in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
client.get{
        url("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search")
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        headers {
                append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer $API_KEY")
        }
        formData {
            parameter("location","NYC") //use this wey
        }

    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?